# Why does $x^n-1$ split over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$? (for $n|p-1$)

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, automorphism-group

Suppose $p$ is prime and $n|p-1$ (I suppose we could take $n$ to be another prime such that it divides $p-1$. Then I am trying to show $x^n-1$ splits into a product of linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_p$. I feel like it should have something to do with $\text{Aut}(C_p)\cong C_{p-1}$ In particular, if $a$ generates $\text{Aut}(C_p)$ then it has order $p-1$. So we take $b=a^{(p-1)/n}$ which clearly has order $n$. I feel that $x^n-1=(x-1)(x-b)(x-b^2)\cdots(x-b^{n-1})$ but unsure if this is the case, or why it is if so. Certainly, if we plug in some numbers then this is true. For example:

$p=3$ and $n=2$ and clearly $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x-2)$

$p=7$ and $n=3$ and $(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)$

$p=11$ and $n=5$ and $(x^5-1)=(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-9)$.

I suppose I could argue $x^n-1$ splits completely because it has $n$ distinct zeroes in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Any help on why this is happening, though?

Comment: $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}_p}$ We just need to show that $\F$ contains $n$ different elements $a$ such that $a^n = 1$. These $a$ must live in the multiplicative group $\F^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$. Writing this additively, we want to find $n$ different elements $a$ in this additive group $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ such that $na = 0$. But it's obvious that these exist: They are simply the multiples of $\frac{p-1}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, the polynomial $X^{p-1}-1$ splits, as any nonzero element is a root.

If $n\mid p-1$, then $X^n-1 \mid X^{p-1}-1$ (this is a classical result, actually the divisibility relation holds in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$), and so $X^n-1$ divides a split polynomial : it must be split.

Another way to see it, as a comment points out, is that $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic, and it's known that if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $m$, then for any $n\mid m$ there are precisely $n$ elements whose order divides $n$, that is, who satisfy $x^n = 1$ : since there are $n$ roots to $X^n-1$, this polynomial splits.

(As you probably noticed, this can be extended to any finite field, changing $p$ into $q$ wherz $q= p^k$ is any prime power)

Comment: It is the fact $x^{p-1}-1$ has $p-1$ different roots in $\mathbb{F}_p$ which shows for $d | p-1, x^d-1$ has $d$ different roots and hence $ \sum_{d | p-1} \mu(d) \frac{p-1}{d}=\varphi(p-1)$ elements of $\mathbf{F}_p^\times$ have order $p-1$ and $\mathbf{F}_p^\times$  is cyclic.

Comment: @reuns that's one way to prove it. Another way to show it is that if $G$ is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a  field $K$, then letting $n$ denote the exponent of $G$, the polynomial $X^n-1$ has $|G|$ roots, so $|G| \leq n$, and so $|G| =n$, and it's an easy exercise to show that in an abelian group, there's always an element of order the exponent of the group; in this case this element has order $|G|$